# Does there exist any android api that returns mediafile bitrate, framerate etc?

Tags: android, media, codec, bitrate

I'm trying to build an android app which generates media file statistics e.g. bitrate for audio & bitrate, frame rate, codec information etc for video.

I have been able to create playlist based on the files available on external storage on mobile device and play them using MediaPlayer apis.

But I haven't found any api so far which lets you extract the above mentioned information from the media files.

I checked AudioTrack class but it doesn't serves the purpose.

It will be absolutely great if some one can share some insights on this.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html

Answer (score 0):

There isn't currently an API for this.

You can probably find an open source package that has media metadata query functionality (I'd imagine [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) can do this). These open source libraries are usually written in C, but can potentially be ported to the [NDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html) (Native Development Kit). Another thing to remember is that bitrate, framerate, and other encoding parameters are generally codec-specific, and some codecs have licensing fees.

Comment: I have been able to compile ffmpeg downloaded from the source [link](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html) following the instructions I found here [link](http://androidcore.com/android-programming-tutorials/641.html). But, I'm getting the same error as many others while using jni on android. I tried with sample hello-jni that comes with ndk bundle. Strangely, I am continuously getting this error: **Exception Ljava/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError; thrown during Lcom/home/test/HelloJni;.<clinit>**.